# VSCode Python test discovery not loading properly because of imports

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest, vscode-extensions

Ive got a directory structure:

```
Business Logic
    excel_format_error_checks.py
tests
    test_excel_format_error_checks.py
```

When I set my import of excel_format_error_checks like below, VSCode test discovery gives an error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Business_Logic'`

test_excel_format_error_checks.py

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from Business_Logic import excel_format_error_checks

class TestExcelFormatErrorChecks(TestCase):

    @patch('Business_Logic.excel_format_error_checks.openpyxl')
    def test_tgl_not_missing_from_titles(self,mock_openpyxl):
      ...
```

If I change the import to `from ..Business_Logic import excel_format_error_checks`,  the test discovery works.

When I then try to run the tests from VSCode test discovery, I get an error because of the @patch path, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Business_Logic'`.

When I try to run the tests from the terminal, I get the error

`ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_excel_format_error_checks Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\brady\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName module = __import__(module_name) File "C:\Users\brady\Desktop\excel_formatting\excel_format_website\api\tests\test_excel_format_error_checks.py", line 6, in <module> from ..Business_Logic import excel_format_error_checks ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Questions, 1.why does test discovery only work when i add the .. to the import
2. How can I fix the issue/ fix the patch path

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the python language, the import usually only looks in the current directory of the file, and your file directory is obviously not in the same folder.

We can use the following code to provide relative paths. Of course, absolute paths are more commonly used.

```
import os
import sys
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../')
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../'))
from BusinessLogic import excel_format_error_checks
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! So is it correct to assume the reason sys.path.append('..') didn't work is because the VSCode test discovery looks in sys.path and could only find a .. path, compared to your code where you provide a path that's complete (but still relative)? And so the reason doing import ..Business_Logic works for test discovery is that VSCode didn't have to look in sys.path for Business_Logic, because Business_Logic was imported directly by the test file when it was run? Sorry if my reasoning doesn't make sense, and thank you anyways haha